# Why does the temperature of bottle conditioning determine the amount of priming sugar?

Tags: fermentation, carbonation, bottle-conditioning, calculations

When using CO2 calculators or the [nomograph on Palmer's site](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter11-4.html) we see that depending on the temperature of your beer, you use a different amount of priming sugar in order to get the same effective carbonation.  Why would temperature effect the amount of CO2?

My (incorrect) logic goes like this:  You put "X" number of yeast cells into a bottle with "Y" amount of food.  When the yeast are done, you have "Z" CO2.  So if you do two bottles, both with X and Y counts, and one bottle is warmer, then all of the food might get consumed sooner (presuming both temperatures are keeping the yeast happy), and you get Z CO2.  But the cooler bottle, once all the food is gone, should also have Z CO2, not Z plus something.

So what is going on that changes the food to CO2 ratio when temperature changes?

Comment: It's not the temperature of bottle conditioning, it's the temperature of the fermented beer that you're adding priming sugar to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're not accounting for is the CO2 produced during fermentation.  The colder the beer ferments, the more CO2 will be in solution in it.  That kinda gives you a "head start" on carbonation.  If you don't account for the CO2 retained, your beer can be either over or under carbonated.

Comment: So when bottling lagers, would you say its a good rule of thumb to bring them up to room temp for a day or two before bottling, to let that extra C02 in suspension bubble out? That way, say, 4oz of Dextrose will give you the same carbonation in a lager as in an ale?

Comment: Very smart Denny!  Excellent.  Not sure why I didn't think of that, but makes perfect sense.

Comment: Graham, that's what I do.  It's not 100% effective, but I find it easier than trying to figure out how much dissolved CO2 is in the beer.  Yeah, I know, I'm lazy....

Comment: co2 is solvent in solutions. the cooler the temperature of the liquid the more co2 can be absorbed. another reason why you want to chill your brew before opening.